# GPU rendering out of memory

Tags: rendering

Why do I have "Out of memory" crash while GPU rendering with the memory peak of 356 when by graphic card has 2GB of memory?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your actual question, but you might get through the render by decreasing the tile size by increasing the number of tiles in the render properties. This should reduce the RAM requirement.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it will also increase render time. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I was thinking about it some more. Is there a utility that can tell you what other things the GPU might be working on? I wonder if something else might be occupying the rest of the RAM. Also, have you tried running it on the command line?

Comment: What operating system are you on, what is your graphics card brand and model? What drivers are you using, are they up to date? What other software is running while you render? There too many variables and too little info to give you any kind answer. It may be that Blender is reporting memory usage wrong, there may be other applications using VRAM, Blender itself may also be using additional memory for viewport and UI, it may also be a bug

Comment: Win10
GTX 960 2GB

Comment: 2gb is not a lot of vRAM, if that is the only GPU on the system you have even less of it available for rendering. Reduce the size of texures, vertices and simplify/optimize your scene as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

As first I must say only for correctness: Does not matter, how much memory have you graphics card. Important is how much **free** memory have your graphics card, when you start render. Keep in mind: system need some video memory for running.

You are not only one who have this problem. I thing Blender have some issues with freeing VRAM. I used Win and now I'm using Linux and it's the same. What help is restart Blender.

About peak of used VRAM - I don't thing this is correct number in case of error. From my experiences, if Blender give you "out of memory" error, this number is incorrect. You can determine exact size of scene by switch to CPU rendering and you can see how much memory is really used for your scene.

Answer (score 0):

best way for work with render and GPU is to use integrated GPU (o a very cheap video card) for the system and use the powerful GPU just for rendering. 
in this way GPU is just used for rendering and nothing else.

if your computer have a integrated VGA try to plug monitor in this one and let the 2GB card unplugged.

try to start rendering in this way